# A density result for arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ergodic-theory, arithmetic-progression

*Note: By upper/lower density, we shall mean the upper/lower asymptotic density as given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).*

**Question:**

For any subset $S \subset \mathbb N$ with positive upper density, does there exists a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the set

$$A_{\varepsilon} := \{z \in \mathbb N \ | \ \text {The set } S_z=\{n~|~nz \in S\}\text { has upper density at least } \varepsilon\}$$

has nonzero lower density?

**Remarks:**

1. This question arose when trying to prove a number theory result involving greatest common denominators of sets of naturals.
2. The corresponding result, if one replaces the set $A_\varepsilon$ with the set  $B := \{z \in \mathbb N \ | \ nz \in S \text { for infinitely many } n \in \mathbb N \}$ is true, and not overly difficult to prove. In fact we even have an explicit bound for the lower density of $B$ - it is at least the upper density of $S$.

Comment: I think this should be true. Davenport and Erdos have some papers on the density of the multiples of some set: https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1936-04.pdf and https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1951-07.pdf These seem quite related, tough I don't see a direct application.

Comment: Yeah, I believe I have a sketch that this is true - a slight extension of the proof of the rest in Remark 2 with quantitative bounds.